# Расставить правильно знаки препинания

Tags: правописание

наступило утро ожили улицы города люди спешат на работу всюду снуют машины

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Наступило утро: ожили улицы города, люди спешат на работу, всюду снуют машины. Это БСП, где содержание первого предложения раскрывается тремя последующими предложениями, связь между которыми также бессоюзная.

Comment: спасибо,а разве двоеточие в 1 классе уже проходят

Comment: Для первого класса лучше использовать более простой вариант:Наступило утро, ожили улицы города, люди спешат на работу, всюду снуют машины. Здесь простое перечисление событий, их взаимосвязь не указывается.

Comment: спасибо большое очень помогли.

Comment: Ну, основы предложений-то можно было найти.

Comment: София, зачем Вы делаете за детей их домашние задания? Не оказывайте им медвежью услугу.